# How to keep assign a constant API Gateway Id

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

we are using VPCE for private API Gateway ,but while redeploying using CFT ,the API Gateway got delete and new API Gateway will create ,which results a new api-gateway-id  .As you know VPCE also use that id to access ,so its very difficult to manage .Could you please let me know how to keep the API Gateway id remains constant or any other solution for this .

Comment: Are you using CDK? What changes between the redeploys?

Answer (score 0):

Resource physical ids change when [resources are replaced](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-update-behaviors.html).  How do we avoid
replacement updates?

- Add IAM policies with `"Effect" : "Deny"` on delete actions for resources you wish to protect.
- Deny delete actions at the organization level with IAM-like [Service Control Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps_syntax.html).
- For stateful resources like databases that have it, set the [deletion policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) attribute to `DeletionPolicy: Retain`.
- [Enable stack protection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-protect-stacks.html) to protect
  against accidential stack deletion.
- If you use the AWS CDK, test against assertions that resource ID have not changed with [testing constructs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/testing.html) or run `cdk diff` to see resource updates before deploying.

PS:  [AWS best practices](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/best-practices-for-developing-cloud-applications-with-aws-cdk/)<sup>*</sup>
advise:  *"Don’t change the scope and ID of stateful resources"*.  For  *stateless* resources like API Gateway, however, it's better to avoid depending on constant physical ids.  Use refs instead.

---

* The linked article addresses CDK apps, but it of course applies to CloudFormation, too.